# force.com cli is missing error in mac for lightining

Tags: force.com, mavensmate, lightning, force-cli

I am trying to configure my force.com cli for lightning plugin in my sublime text editor.

I have followed some articles but still I am getting that error.

[image]

Comment: Did you install force.com CLI first on your MAC?

Comment: I dont know hot to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great blog post [here](http://www.mobileandemerging.technology/force-com-cli-why-didnt-i-install-this-sooner/) about getting started with the force.com cli including install instructions for the MAC.

> For those using a Mac, go to https://force-cli.heroku.com and download
>   the Mac version. All you get in your Downloads folder is a single file
>   called "force". There is no installer, you just have to put this file
>   someplace that makes sense. I moved it to a place where my path could
>   see it and made sure it was executable for me.
>
> mv ~/Downloads/force /usr/local/bin
>
> chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/force

Comment: This installs force.com cli for my terminal. But I am still getting the above error.

Comment: @Monish did you verify that the force cli works after install? Looking at the Readme file that is what is required for the plugin https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning/blob/master/README.md